# Pagination in many-to-many mapping in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, many-to-many

I have two tables with Many-To-Many mappings. Tables are `content` and `tag`. So, I have another table `content_tag` to normalize the many-to-many relationship. But, I am having problem in pagination. As example, when I am fetching a tag by name it returns a single `tag` object, but with multiple `content` object nested inside. I know how to do pagination for `tag`, but my question is how can I make pagination for the nested `content` object in a single `tag` object. Please see my result below, which I am getting from POSTMAN.

```
{
  "id": 12,
  "tag": "Viral",
  "contents": [
    {
      "id": 15,
      "idHide": "0",
      "listCategory": {
        "id": 11,
        "title": "Dramai",
        "titleBn": "&#2465;&#2509;&#2480;&#2494;&#2478;&#2494;&#2439;",
        "status": "active"
      },
      "title": "Cat",
      "titleBn": "#99",
      "brief": "uytyyyy",
      "briefBn": "#495",
      "highlight": "0",
      "dim": "0",
      "sticky": "0",
      "status": "active",
      "createdAt": "Jan 24, 2018 3:08:34 PM",
      "listTag": [
        {
          "id": 12,
          "title": "Viral"
        },
        {
          "id": 13,
          "title": "Progress"
        },
        {
          "id": 14,
          "title": "Limit"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please note `contents` tag in response is a list of content object for `viral` tag. Sometimes `contents` array size gone over 50 objects. So, I want to implement pagination for that. How can I implement pagination for content?